# Should I use require or require_relative in minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

I have a simple test class

```
require "test_helper"

describe ClassUnderTest do
end
```

to run this I have to type 'ruby -Itest test/class_under_test.rb'

If instead I use `require_relative '../test_helper.rb' in the test class I don't have to add the extra -Itest when I run it, so I simply type`ruby test/class_under_test.rb`

Is there a reason to use require vs require_relative?

Answer (score 0):

`require` is for loading files from the `$LOAD_PATH`. `require_relative` is for loading files relative to the file the call to `require_relative` is in. In this case, it looks like you want the latter, so `require_relative` is the correct one to use.

Comment: both solutions work, I was wondering if there is a preferred way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, always use the simplest code.  In this case:

```
require 'test_helper'
```

More specifically, requiring test_helper (or spec_helper/rails_helper for rspec) is a common idiom, and is almost always seen as `require 'test_helper'`.